# Android: Если Toast-сообщение стоит ИМЕННО В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ, Studio подчёркивает его красным

Tags: android, adapter, listener, toast

```
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                String Item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



//ПРОБЕМА ТУТ:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Слушатель сработал! Выбрана позиция" + Item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        };
        BarType.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
    }
```

В любом другом месте с этим сообщением всё ок. Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишите код внутри переопределённого метода внутри тела анонимного класса, реализующего интерфейс. Засим `this` в данном месте - это ссылка на этот самый анонимный класс. И он не наследует `Context`, который вам надо передать первым аргументом метода `Toast#makeText`.

В вашем случае можно котекст взять из аргмента-вьюхи. Т.е. заменить `this` на `view.getContext()`

Comment: Юрий, с getContext() вообще вся строка красная

Comment: Крайне странно. У вас точно так как я имел в виду написано? `Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Слушатель сработал! Выбрана позиция" + Item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Да, именно так написано

Comment: А что за ошибка возникает? При наведении мыши на красное должна плашка с пояснением появляться.

Comment: Появляется:

Требуется тип Toast
Предоставлен void

И дальше длииииннное описание этой функции

Comment: Это из за попытки приравнять результат вызова метода void show переменной с типом Toast. Просто удалите `Toast toast =`